# How to Retrieve Text Next to a Check Box when only Passed the Input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set up like so:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="box" checked>Frankie</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="box" checked>Samuel</label>
```

Then I have a function that is only able to listen for `.on('change'...)` So within the scope of this function, when I pass: `console.log(this)`, I only get `<label><input type="checkbox" class="box" checked>` in the console. I am not surprised at this result, but at the same time I'm not sure what more I can do differently to get the text associated with them, i.e. Frankie and Samuel.

**Question:** How do I access the text when only passed the input itself?

**Note:** I prefer to keep my wraps as is, and ideally everything as is. I'm not sure if adding id's to elements will be allowed for this application.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `value` attribute? That is what it is for.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/wiki/Traversing_the_DOM

Comment: @Quentin You're right I should be. That fixed it right up. For my particular use case, using `value` works great. I suppose it was a bit anti-climactic, but I will leave the question up just out of curiosity. Perhaps there is a way to retrieve the adjacent text. It might come in handy someday.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not interested in using the `value` attribute then try this approach:

```js
function getNextText(el) {
   return el.parentElement.innerHTML.match(/\>([\w\s\d]+)/)[1];
}

$('.box').on('change', function(e) {
   var adjacentText = getNextText(this);
  
   console.log(adjacentText);
})
```

It works well.